# odd function behavior, works with one param, partially works with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has a few clickable icons that fade in different content and a function that takes an event (from click handler) or variable (from a get request, to show the right content when a related link is clicked from elsewhere). Everything works as expected when clicking, but when I try to use the variable param the function goes into the right if statement, but the dom manipulations don't happen just the test console.logs. Wondering if anyone has an idea why? I was using eval to do this before, so I'd rather get this working than go back! Thanks

```
page = <?php echo (int) $_GET["pg"] ?>;
if(page){
    servicePage(event,page);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".service_button").click(servicePage);
})

function servicePage(event, pg =0){

console.log(this.id);
console.log(pg);    
if(this.id == 1 || pg == 1){
    console.log('here');
  $( "div.service_page2" ).hide();
  $( "div.service_page3" ).hide();
  $( "div.service_page4" ).hide();
  $("div.service_page1").fadeIn();
  $( ".service_button1" ).animate({
  width:"100%"},300);
  $( ".service_button2" ).animate({
  width:"50%"},300);
   $( ".service_button3" ).animate({
   width:"50%"},300);
   $( ".service_button4" ).animate({
   width:"50%"},300);

}

if(this.id == 2 || pg == 2){
    console.log('whut');
        $( "div.service_page1" ).hide();
  $( "div.service_page3" ).hide();
  $( "div.service_page4" ).hide();
  $("div.service_page2").fadeIn();
   $( ".service_button1" ).animate({
 width:"50%"},300);
   $( ".service_button2" ).animate({
 width:"100%"},300);
   $( ".service_button3" ).animate({
 width:"50%"},300);
   $( ".service_button4" ).animate({
 width:"50%"},300);
}

if(this.id == 3 || pg == 3){
     $( "div.service_page1" ).hide();
      $( "div.service_page2" ).hide();
      $( "div.service_page4" ).hide();
      $("div.service_page3").fadeIn();
        $( ".service_button1" ).animate({
     width:"50%"},300);
       $( ".service_button2" ).animate({
     width:"50%"},300);
       $( ".service_button3" ).animate({
     width:"100%"},300);
       $( ".service_button4" ).animate({
     width:"50%"},300);
}

if(this.id == 4 ||pg == 4){
     $( "div.service_page1" ).hide();
      $( "div.service_page2" ).hide();
      $( "div.service_page3" ).hide();
      $("div.service_page4").fadeIn();
        $( ".service_button1" ).animate({
     width:"50%"},300);
       $( ".service_button2" ).animate({
     width:"50%"},300);
       $( ".service_button3" ).animate({
     width:"50%"},300);
       $( ".service_button4" ).animate({
     width:"100%"},300);
    console.log('why');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have those elements in DOM when you're trying to call `servicePage(event,page)`. You can easily drop this by moving this call in `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
var page = <?php echo (int) $_GET["pg"] ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".service_button").click(servicePage);
  if(page){
    servicePage(null, page);
  }
});
```

Also, you can drop the argument completely if you just use `call` to pass the correct content into the function (as you don't use the `event` param at all):

```
function servicePage() {
  switch (+this.id)
    case 1: // ...
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".service_button").click(servicePage);
  if (page) {
    servicePage.call({id: page});
  }
});
```

---

As for the function itself, it can (and should) be simplified. Note that for each value of param, you do two things: activate the `page` element, and deactivate 'other' ones. One possible approach to do this:

```
function activatePage(pageNo) {
  $('div.service_page' + pageNo).fadeIn();
  $('.service_button' + pageNo).animate({ width: '100%' }, 300);
}

function deactivatePagesOtherThan(activePageNo) {
  var inactivePages = [1,2,3,4].filter(function(no) {
    return no !== activePageNo;
  });
  var inactivePageSelectors = inactivePages.map(function(no) {
    return 'div.service_page' + no;
  });
  var inactiveButtonSelectors = inactivePages.map(function(no) {
    return '.service_button' + no;
  });
  $(inactivePageSelectors.join(',')).hide();
  $(inactiveButtonSelectors.join(',')).animate({ width: '50%' }, 300);
}

function servicePage() {
  var no = +this.id;
  if (no >= 1 && no <= 4) {
    deactivatePagesOtherThan(no);
    activatePage(no);
  }
}
```